# how can i create a circular carousel or circular scroll view?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve a circular carousel loop or scrollview loop that is based around the borders of a circular view.
I will attach a photo of what I was able to accomplish which was a normal view not a scrollview.

[image: this thing]

Comment: Maybe you could get some inspiration from https://github.com/usmanfaisal60/react-native-rotating-menu#readme

Comment: @MichaelBahl this is spot on. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

if any one was wondering, I used the react-native-reanimated-carousel library with the circular tutorial in the library documentation and was able to accomplish the wanted result.